# How to get fprintf to display higher precision?

Tags: matlab, printf

I am trying to use the following fprintf code

```
      n
      m
     fprintf('The minimum value of the modulus of the image of C_r is %d \n\nThe correspoding point is at %d \n\n',m,n)
```

and I get the result

```
  n =

  3.632213809443102 + 3.680287679864827i


m =

   5.170831128945713

The minimum value of the modulus of the image of C_r is 5.170831e+000 

The correspoding point is at        3.632214e+000
```

where I have printed the values of n and m separately in order to show how I would like them to come out --  how do I get fprintf to display the numbers to a higher precision? I tried changing the     %d terms but to no avail

Comment: why are you using `%d` for floating points? why not `%f` or `%g`?

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/formatting-strings.html#bq05n1r-1

Comment: because I don't really know what I'm doing, to be honest. I looked through a manual and thought I was supposed to use %d. I'll try your answer and see

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about

```
fprintf( '%.15f\n', m );
```

prints with 15 digits

Comment: it still cuts off the '+i...' bit, do I have to put in the real and imaginary parts separately?

Comment: it seems like there's no way around it. See [this post](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/94170).

Comment: maybe: `fprintf('%.15f + %.15fi\n',real(z),imag(z))`

Comment: if you dislike seeing "0.1 + -0.2i" (plus then minus), you could use `'%.15f %+.15fi\n'` instead as format string